# NSString initWithBytes returns nil when given wchar_t array containing Chinese characters

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, nsstring, wchar-t

I've got a custom C++ string class in my iOS app that is based on an array of `wchar_t`.  I have a method to convert it to `NSString` that looks like this:

```
NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:(const void *)mArray
      length:sizeof(wchar_t) * mLength 
      encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding]autorelease];
return str;
```

I've got a case where the input string contains some Chinese characters (specifically 新譯本), and `initWithBytes` returns nil.  There is nothing in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithBytes%3alength%3aencoding%3a) about the method returning nil; is this an error condition?  Does anyone know what kind of thing might make the method kick back a nil result?

Comment: Could you show a small self-contained example? I have tested your code with `wchar_t * mArray = L"新譯本";` and got no problems.

Comment: @MartinR - It's sorted now.  The `wchar` array that was passed in sometimes had UTF-16 characters added in, and the two encodings handle multibyte characters differently.  Apparently if `initWithBytes` gets invalid data it returns nil.  I'll post an answer when I'm allowed to.

Comment: @Mr.Jefferson : now you can post it as answer...

Comment: @FahimParkar - Right you are.  Done.

Comment: I strongly recommend using UTF-8 and avoiding wchar_t if at all possible. The C and C++ language don't even specify what encoding is used for wchar_t, it could be 16 or 32 bits, it could be bigendian or littleendian. UTF-8 avoids all these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `wchar` array that was passed in sometimes had UTF-16 characters in it, and UTF-16 encodes multibyte characters differently.  And if `initWithBytes` gets invalid data, it returns `nil`.